# How can I show an HTML-Code as a Website inside an app with Xamarin.Forms, C#?

Tags: c#, html, xamarin, webview

I have following problem: I wrote a HTML-Code which shows a variable List as table when I press the Button. I did so far, that the table get showed in PDF in a Print Service. But the table has some sort functions and on a PDF one can't use them. So I try to show the HTML as a Website in Webview in the App, where one can use the function. The code for the code behind is the following:

```
public ICommand PrintCommand => new AsyncCommand(Print);

        private async Task Print()
        {
            // New up the Razor template and set the model property
            var printTemplate = new ListPrintTemplate
            {
                Model = FilteredList,
            };

            // Generate the HTML
            var htmlString = printTemplate.GenerateString();

            // Create a source for the webview
            var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource{ Html = htmlString };

            // Create and populate the Xamarin.Forms.WebView
            var browser = new WebView { Source = htmlSource };

            var printService = Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IPrintService>();
            printService.Print(browser, $"{Res.Probe}-{FilteredList}");
        }
```

I have still the printService in the last lines. I looked over the libraries and the Microsoft documentation but can't help myself.

Comment: You are creating a WebView control but not assigning it to a view hierarchy so it will not be displayed anywhere.

Comment: Can you give me a hint for solving this?

Comment: assuming this is in a ContentPage, something like `this.Content = browser;`